# CrawlSpider (Scrapy) not parsed

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

In Scrapy, I'm using a LinkExtractor to crawl rusplast.com.

Data is not parsed

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class RusplastSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'rusplast_crawl'
  allowed_domailns = ['rusplast.com']
  start_urls = ['https://rusplast.com/catalog/abs-plastic/']

  rules = (
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='abs-plastic', deny='/?BRAND')),
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/abs-plastic/\d+/'), callback='parse_items', follow=True)
  )
        
  def parse_items(self, response):
    yield {
          'Name': response.css('h1.header::text').get().strip(),
         }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule is capturing everything that would be considered by your second rule, and so nothing is making it to your second rule, to be parsed by your `parse_item` method.  Simply remove your first rule, and turn the tuple into a list and it should work just fine.

```
class RusplastSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'rusplast_crawl'
  allowed_domailns = ['rusplast.com']
  start_urls = ['https://rusplast.com/catalog/abs-plastic/']

  rules = [
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/abs-plastic/\d+/'), callback='parse_items', follow=True)
  ]
        
  def parse_items(self, response):
    yield {
          'Name': response.css('h1.header::text').get().strip(),
         }
```